# ggplot2 not plotting error bars with stat summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a bar graph with ggplot2 and am trying to add the confidence intervals. I have the following code (in a new project with only ggplot2 loaded):

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
stimuli <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 1, times = 50)
dv_1 <- rnorm(150, mean = 3.5, sd = 0.89)

#simdat<-as.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)
#simdat<-data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)
simdat<-cbind.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)

ggplot(simdat, aes(x = reorder(stimuli, dv_1), y = dv_1)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", fill = "#1F78B4", width = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="grey70", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2)
```

This plots the means, but for the error bars I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
```

I also tried

```
ggplot(simdat, aes(x = reorder(stimuli, dv_1), y = dv_1)) +
  stat_summary(fun = match.fun(mean), geom = "bar", fill = "#1F78B4", width = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="grey70", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2)
```

As suggested in the comments, but received the same error. I am using R version 4.1.2 and ggplot2 3.3.5. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Below is the complete output

[image]

Comment: Not able to reproduce your issue. Your code works fine and I don't get a warning when using `simdat <- data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)` on R 4.1.1 using ggplot2 3.3.5.

Comment: I'm using R 4.1.2 and ggplot2 3.3.5

Comment: We cannot reproduce your error you see here, so it's definitely not the code that we see which is the problem... therefore it must be the code we DON'T SEE.  Can you post the `simdat` data.frame?  How are you defining `simdat`?  If I run the code as you've pasted, we don't have `simdat`.  What happens when you define `simdat` in the code above as `data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)`?  Do you still get the error?

Comment: @chemdork123 I updated my question to include the ggplot2 library and how I saved the dataframe - I tried all variants of `simdat<-as.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)`, `simdat<-cbind.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)` and `simdat<-data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)`

Comment: @becbot what is the rest of the error message?  (the line below `"computation failed..."`)?  I'm guessing that one or more of your reference objects in the plot code is also represented in the local environment.  Try using a different data frame name and also designating the data frame in one statement.  i.e. `df <- data.frame(stimuli = c(...), dv_1 = c(...))`.  Then use `df` in the `ggplot()` call.  If you still get an error, you'll know it has nothing to do with that.  Importantly, clear the local environment first: `rm(list=ls())` to remove `dv_1` and `stimuli` vectors.

Comment: @chemdork123 that is the entire error message, there's nothing else (I added a screenshot). I tried your suggestion for the dataframe and removing/renaming variables but still nothing

Comment: I can't reproduce your error here (R 4.0.2 and ggplot2 3.3.5).  My guess is either something in your install of `ggplot2` is messed up (try running `install.packages('ggplot2')` again).  Or one or more of the functions is masked, so it's not running the one from `ggplot2`, but a different function of the same name.  Try running the same code with every function explicitly stated via `package::function()`, so `ggplot2::ggplot()` + `ggplot2::stat_summary()`.. etc.

Answer (score 2):

To use the 'mean_cl_boot' function in 'stat_summary()', try installing the 'Hmisc' package first. In my case it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works,as suggested by @stefan check the way you the define `stimuli` data frame.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1234)
stimuli <- rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 1, times = 50)
dv_1 <- rnorm(150, mean = 3.5, sd = 0.89)
```

Sample code:

```
library (ggplot2)

#simdat<-as.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)
simdat<-cbind.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)

ggplot(simdat, aes(x = reorder(stimuli, dv_1), y = dv_1)) +
  stat_summary(fun = match.fun(mean), geom = "bar", fill = "#1F78B4", width = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar",
               colour="grey70", position=position_dodge(1), width=.2)
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: When I use `simdat <- as.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)` I get the following error: `Warning in as.data.frame.vector(x, ..., nm = nm) :
  'row.names' is not a character vector of length 150 -- omitting it. Will be an error!` if I use `simdat <- data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)` I get the same problem as what I initially posted :/ I also tried restarting R. Could it be due to the R version?

Comment: @becbot, not sure, but try simdat<-cbind.data.frame(stimuli, dv_1)

Comment: still the same `Warning: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:` error message

Comment: @becbot otherwise I am using "R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)". You can use R.version.string to check your R version

Comment: I'm using R.4.1.2 - I recently updated it and had copied the code from a previous project (where it had worked), which is why I am wondering if it is a versioning issue

Comment: @becbot replace fun =match.fun(mean) and use library(ggplot2)

Comment: still nothing using `stat_summary(fun = match.fun(mean), geom = "bar", fill = "#1F78B4", width = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)`. I also opened a new project and loaded only the ggplot2library in case there was any package clashes